# Update/replace file string on remote computer using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to update file string on remote computer. In my script i'm using following code.

```
Get-Content Clients.txt | ForEach-Object \\{ Get-Item "\\$_\D$\Runtime\run.properties" \\} | Replace-FileString.ps1 -Pattern '$PropName=.*' -Replacement '$PropName=$PropValue' -Overwrite
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Replace-FileString.ps1 : The term 'Replace-FileString.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

I even tried with `Replace-FileString` and i'm getting same error.

Is this the correct way or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You specify a script name. PS does not find this script, so insert the path (target system) of your script - e.g. "c:....\Replace-FileString.ps1".
If it's in the same dir then just ".\Replace-FileString.ps1".

Comment: Hi, I was under impression that Replace-FileString.ps1 comes with Powershell bundle. Is there any other way to update the file string on remote computer?

Comment: @jks: there is the `-replace` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following command and it is working perfectly

```
Get-Content Clients.txt | ForEach-Object { (Get-Content -Path "\\$_\D$\Runtime\run.properties") -replace "provisioner.events.monitor=.*","provisioner.events.monitor=JagadeeshTest"  | Set-Content -Path "\\$_\D$\Runtime\run.properties"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Replace-FileString.ps1` is part of [psappdeploytoolkit](http://psappdeploytoolkit.com) and will not be present on a system unless you have specifically installed it.

You can instead use `replace` ([more info on this command](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/03/21/use-powershell-to-replace-text-in-strings/)) instead:

```
ForEach ($client in (Get-Content Clients.txt)) {
    (Get-Content "\\$client\D$\Runtime\run.properties") -replace "$PropName=.*","$PropName=$PropValue" | 
        Out-File "\\$client\D$\Runtime\run.properties"
}
```